# HAProxy with Roundrobin working only on 2 of 3 MySQL servers, why?

Tags: mysql, cluster, mariadb, haproxy

Good day.

I'm following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3) to configure HAProxy to balance with roundrobin between 3 MySQL servers *(db1, db2, db3)* in a MariaDB Galera cluster *(working perfectly)*.

However I have a problem. In the tutorial there's a "Testing Load Balancing and Failover" area, in which I must execute the command `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u haproxy_root -p -e "show variables like 'server_id'"` to see the same result along with the server name. Executing the same command more than once will show the roundrobin jumping between `db1` and `db2` and viceversa... it never pass to `db3`. I'm reading everywhere and roundrobin should jump between all the servers, but in my case it just work between db1 and db2, why not in db3?

Check my HAProxy configuration:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log global
    retries 2
    timeout connect 3000
    timeout server 5000
    timeout client 5000

listen mysql-cluster
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server db1 172.28.109.10:3306 check
    server db2 172.28.109.11:3306 check
    server db3 172.28.109.12:3306 check

listen 127.0.0.1:8080
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth monitor_user:password
```

Those 3 servers are properly declared in my MariaDB Galera Cluster configuration file, and they share behave perfectly in between. Check part of it here:

```
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://171.28.109.10, 171.28.109.11, 171.28.109.12"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='171.28.109.10'
wsrep_node_name='db1'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth="user:password"
```

What am I missing? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you confirming that there is no connection request to db3 ?

Comment: Check the haproxy's status page, perhaps its health check is failing for db3